# Certificate signed by an unknown authority in keychain after upgrading to El Capitan

Tags: macos, keychain, certificate

I've found a random certificate in my keychain after upgrading to El Capitan‎ on both my Macs. It's called "ENTIDAD PUBLICA EMPRESARIAL RED.ES". It's showing a warning that it was signed by an unknown authority.

Does anyone know what this is used for?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may check the validity of the certificate including the certificate chain  here:

[DigiCert® SSL Installation Diagnostics Tool](https://www.digicert.com/help/)

[image]

or here:

[Check your web servers encryption](https://ssl-tools.net/webservers/)

[image]

Both checks show the same chain with different results though:

The certificate *ENTIDAD PUBLICA EMPRESARIAL RED.ES* as well as the intermediate certificate *AC Componentes Informáticos* seem to be ok.
SSL-Tools and OS X El Capitan can't properly detect the validity of the root certificate though.

Answer (score 0):

[Red.es](http://www.red.es/redes/) seems to be a Spanish telecommunications provider. [They say](http://www.dominios.es/dominios/en/sobre-nosotros) they're "responsible for the .es TLD:

> Dominos ".es" is responsible for managing the Internet Domain Names Registry for the country code ".es". The registry management tasks include processing applications and assigning new domains.
>
> It is a part of the public business entity Red.es.

[ICANN seems to agree](http://icannwiki.com/RED.ES). It looks like they sell their own SSL certificates for domains, and so they'd need a root certificate on your computer - otherwise, your browser would complain.

If you don't visit .es websites often, I'd be inclined to disable that certificate. It's one more company that, if infiltrated, their root certificate could* be used to impersonate any website. Like, say... [this one](http://google.com).

---

<sup>*I'm not entirely sure about that last one, I'm not an expert on certificate chains. It's possible that this root CA is only valid for `*.es`  domains. Not sure.</sup>